# How to deform armature and keep its volume?

Tags: mesh, armature

Is there a way to deform the mesh below, along the red guides? I want to preserve the full volume and shape of the original. At the moment it always is tapered, even if "Preserve Volume" is turned on.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you try to move your arm with an armature but the bone deforms the arm too much and you want to correct the proportions.

To do so I think you need to use *Shapekeys* and *Drivers*, *Shapekeys* will allow you to correct the shape and *Drivers* will allow your bone to control the shapekey value:

- Create your mesh and armature, parent the mesh to the armature *With Automatic Weight*, in the *Armature* modifier enable the *Display Edit Mode* and the *On Cage* options, bend the arm the way you want, in *Object* mode create 2 shapekeys for your mesh, select the second shapekey, go in *Edit* mode and modify the mesh so that it gets the shape you want:

[image]

- Back to Object mode, right click on the *Shapekey Value* and click on *Add Driver*, it opens a panel, in this panel > *Object* > choose the armature and the arm bone, *Type* >  choose the type of transformation the bone will affect (here *Z Rotation*), and *Space > Local Space*:

[image]
[image]

- Click on the Shapekey Value again and this time choose *Open Drivers Editor*, you should see the driver curve, select all and type <kbd>V</kbd> to make the curve straight, rotate the curve until you're satisfied of its effect on the mesh. Now when you'll rotate the arm the mesh will bend and also apply the shapekey you've created.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is very useful. I was not aware of how Shape Keys. I'm still having a bit of trouble to understand how the curve translates to the key positions, but I'm getting there. Thanks again for the instructions! :)

Comment: on one axis of the driver's curve you will have the rotation value, on the other you'll have the shapekey value, you can handle this curve like the graph editor curve: add vertices, move handles, etc... Another solution is to not use drivers and to keyframe the shapekey depending on the arm movement, but drivers have the advantage of doing it automatically

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question and I hope that you find the community helpful.

IF I'm understanding correctly, if your only objective is to stretch your edges among the red dashed lines, you can press 1 on your row of numbers above the letters of your keyboard (not the numpad on the far right) to enter vertex select mode, select the appropriate vertex, and drag it out to the desired location. Alternatively for this specific operation, you can press 2 to enter edge select mode, select the diagonal edge between the two corners, press S to enter scale mode, and increase the size so that it meets the desired location.